# Explanation about notation

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation

Can anyone explain to me what $C[x^2,x^3]_{(x^2,x^3)}$ means? It is connected with localizations but it is unclear to me what it means exactly.

Comment: $R_I$ mean localization of $R$ at $I$....

Comment: I know that. But in this case isn't $(x^2,x^3)$ the same as $(x^2)$? Also $(x^2)$ is not a prime ideal so how can we take the localization of a ring at an ideal that is not prime?

Comment: Oh yes... $(x^2,x^3)$ is same as $(x^2)$... I am not sure about the case in which it is not a prime ideal.. let some expert help us...

Comment: Notice that we are confined to the ring $R=C[x^2,x^3]\subset C[x]$. Actually, $(x^2,x^3)\neq (x^2)$ because $x\notin R$. :)

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld, I see. In $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$ the ideal $(x^2,x^3)$ consists of all the polynomials that have no terms of degree $0$ and $1$. The ideal $(x^2,x^3)$ on the other hand consists of all the polynomials that have no terms of degree $0,1$ and $3$. Is that correct?

Comment: @KarlKronenfeld : Oh yes... I was thinking $x^3=x.x^2\in(x^2)$ so, $(x^2)=(x^2,x^3)$but then i see that my ring $\mathbb{C}(x^2,x^3)$ does not contain $x$.. A very good observation.. Thanks for the clarification :)

Comment: @user53970 Maybe you meant $(x^2)$ in your second to last sentence. Then, you are indeed correct.

Answer (score 0):

As we can form all monomials with degree $>1$ by multiplication of $x^2,x^3$, the ring $R = C[x^2,x^3]$ is given by those polynomials in $C[x]$ where the coefficient of $x$ vanishes. Thus, the ideal $(x^2,x^3)$ is given by those polynomials in $C$ where the coefficient of $x$ and the constant term vanish.

We have $C[x^2,x^3]/(x^2,x^3) \cong C$ and consequently - if $C$ is an integral domain - $I=(x^2,x^3)$ is a prime ideal. So localization of R at I is well-defined.

Comment: Indeed $C$ should be $\mathbb{C}$. Your answer was very clear. I just need one little clarification: Can you explain in a little more detail why $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]_{(x^2,x^3)}\cong \mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$?

Comment: @user53970 No, he can't, because he made a mistake: $R$ is not local (better say, it is not local no matter $C\ne 0$ is).

Comment: For instance $1+x^2\in R\setminus I$.

Comment: Oh, indeed, $I$ is not the only maximal ideal, I am very sorry! I will delete the wrong part of my answer. Thank you for the corrections!